# Extracting "object contents" printout from a c++ const ref in gdb?

Tags: python, c++, debugging, gdb

Consider the following example, called for instance `test-types-gdb-printout.cpp` (which emulates a similar situation in my current, more complex, debugging process):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

namespace Some { namespace Stuff {

template<typename Type>
class MyVect {
  public:
    MyVect();
    MyVect(Type x, Type y);
    Type AddComps();
    operator const Type*() const;
    operator Type*();
    Type x;
    Type y;
};

template<typename Type>
MyVect<Type>::MyVect() {
}
template<typename Type>
MyVect<Type>::MyVect(Type _x, Type _y) {
  x = _x;
  y = _y;
}
template<typename Type>
Type MyVect<Type>::AddComps() {
  return x+y;
}
template < typename Type >
MyVect< Type >::operator const Type*() const {
  return &x;
}
template < typename Type >
MyVect< Type >::operator Type*() {
  return &x;
}

typedef MyVect<int> MyVecti;
}}

int main() {
  Some::Stuff::MyVecti mvi(5,10);
  const Some::Stuff::MyVecti& mvic = mvi;
  Some::Stuff::MyVecti* mvip = new Some::Stuff::MyVecti(30,12);
  printf("Result is: %d ; then %d\n", mvi.AddComps(), mvip->AddComps()); // line 46
  delete mvip;
  return 0;
}
```

I compile this with:

```sh
g++ -g test-types-gdb-printout.cpp -o test-types-gdb-printout.exe
```

... and then I run it in the `gdb` debugger as so:

```
$ gdb -ex "b test-types-gdb-printout.cpp:46" -ex "r" -ex "p mvi" -ex "p mvic" -ex "p mvip" --args ./test-types-gdb-printout.exe
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.3) 7.7.1
...
Reading symbols from ./test-types-gdb-printout.exe...done.
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4007e7: file test-types-gdb-printout.cpp, line 50.
Starting program: /tmp/test-types-gdb-printout.exe 

Breakpoint 1, main () at test-types-gdb-printout.cpp:50
50    printf("Result is: %d ; then %d\n", mvi.AddComps(), mvip->AddComps());
$1 = {x = 5, y = 10}
$2 = (const Some::Stuff::MyVecti &) @0x7fffffffdc30: {x = 5, y = 10}
$3 = (Some::Stuff::MyVecti *) 0x602010
(gdb)
```

Note that in `gdb`, when I `p`rint:

- `mvi`, which is of type `Some::Stuff::MyVecti`, I get a printout only of the object contents (i.e. its fields/properties names and values) - that is, `{x = 5, y = 10}`
- `mvip`, which is a pointer of type `Some::Stuff::MyVecti*`, I get a printout of the address only - that is, `(Some::Stuff::MyVecti *) 0x602010`
- `mvic`, which is a const reference, of type `const Some::Stuff::MyVecti&`, I get a printout of both address and object contents - that is, `(const Some::Stuff::MyVecti &) @0x7fffffffdc30: {x = 5, y = 10}`

So this is the thing: in the actual program that I'm debugging, at the breakpoint of interest, I have exactly this kind of a const reference. Now, I would like to use the object contents printout *only*  - but in `gdb`'s Python. Just the regular printout I can get in Python with, say, `gdb.execute("print...")`:

```
(gdb) python print(gdb.execute("print mvic"))
$4 = (const Some::Stuff::MyVecti &) @0x7fffffffdc30: {x = 5, y = 10}
```

.... but this gives me both address (and type) - and the actual object contents printout.

Now, of course, given that I'm in Python, I could just parse the string there (either through split at spaces, or something more complicated) - but I was wondering if there is any way to obtain only the object contents printout `{x = 5, y = 10}` either directly from `gdb` (via `gdb.execute`), or through some specialized method of the GDB Python API?

Answer (score 0):

Meh - seems the answer was already in the question - if the "object contents" are printed when the variable is of actual class type (i.e., not a ref, nor a pointer) - then simply try to cast the const ref to the actual class, that is:

```
(gdb) python print(gdb.execute("print (Some::Stuff::MyVecti)mvic"))
$7 = {x = 5, y = 10}
```

... *however*, note that this doesn't actually end up in Python, it is simply `gdb.execute` dumping its output to stdout, which can be proven by:

```
(gdb) python print("AA" + str(gdb.execute("print (Some::Stuff::MyVecti)mvic")))
$9 = {x = 5, y = 10}      # this is on gdb level
AANone                    # this is from gdb's Python
```

... but there is a way around it, by using `gdb.parse_and_eval`:

```
(gdb) python print("AA"+str(gdb.parse_and_eval( "(Some::Stuff::MyVecti)mvic" )))
AA{x = 5, y = 10}
```

Well, hope that was it with this problem...